How to write "Production/Packaging/Bottling Line" in Japanese?
How to write "Line" in japanese considering I want to mean Production/Packaging/Bottling line ?
線 <= for me it's line but like something you draw
台詞 <= there is also this one, but it's more for fishing
ライン <= should be the good one ?
I want a term to be generic for that.
Any idea?

[台詞]{≪せりふ≫} is a line of dialog.  Like lines that actors have to memorize.  Not sure where you got fishing from...

I've found this as a fishing line also. Maybe was a wrong translation ?

Here ya go: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E7%94%9F%E7%94%A3%E6%96%B9%E5%BC%8F
Apparently I must add more characters to submit.
